# What is the difference between 「運転手【うんてんしゅ】」 and 「車掌【しゃしょう】」?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, kanji

According to the dictionary, 運転手 means driver and 車掌 means conductor. So, 運転手 would be any person at the controls/steering wheel of any vehicle, while 車掌 would be someone who "is in charge of a train and travels with it, but does not drive it" (according to an English dictionary. I am not an English native speaker so I can't grasp the difference between both words in English either). So, the latter is only for trains? and if he does not drive, what does a 車掌 do in a train?

If you could provide some example sentences that illustrate the difference between both words, it would be nice.

よろしくお願いします！

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[運転手]{うんてんしゅ}` is responsible for driving the vehicle like the car, the bus or the train.
As you suppose, `[車掌]{しゃしょう}` only applies to the person who works on the train.
`[車掌]{しゃしょう}` takes care of other than driving the train duties like...

> - Closing door while maintaining customer's safety
> - Informing the next station name
> - Taking care of the sick person while the train is on the way to next station
> - (If you ride the bullet train) Confirming if you are in the right train by checking the ticket.
> - (If you stop at an unmanned train station in rural area) Collecting your train ticket (to make sure you are not cheating...)

`[運転手]{うんてんしゅ}` always stays in the first car of the train while `[車掌]{しゃしょう}` is usually in the last car (but `[車掌]{しゃしょう}`may move to the other cars).

By the way you don't use `[運転手]{うんてんしゅ}` for the person driving the airplane or the ship.
They are called `[操縦士]{そうじゅうし}`. A pilot of the airplane you can call `[パイロット]{ぱいろっと}` which came directly from the word "pilot".

I could not figure out the good sentences though I hope it gives you an idea.

Comment: @JACK thank you for the edit :)

Comment: @naruto thank you for the edit. I should check my answer more carefully...